# How to open a separate program with C++ / OS X

Tags: c++, macos

How can I open a program (.exe or .app) using my C++ program?
Like iTunes, Safari, Pages.

For example;

If I wanted to manually write into a "example.txt", "example.docx" or "example.pages" file, how could I get that file to open the TextEdit, M Word or Pages programs/applications rather than write from inside the Terminal.

I'm not talking about fstream, as thats all I can find on the topic. I feel I've got that pretty down packed (basic example code below)

```
cout << "Enter File Name:\n" << endl;
cin >> fileName;
char a;
cin.get(a);

outStream.open(fileName.c_str());

cout << "\nWhat would you like to write?\n" << endl;
getline(cin, fileWrite);

cout << "\nWriting to " << fileName << endl;
outStream << fileWrite;
outStream.close();
```

While I want my program to be able to Read/Write in streams, I want to also be able to add an option of having the ACTUAL document open so you can MANUALLY Read or Write into it along with the programs edit features and whatnot without using the "system()" command (as I've read that it has too many risks depending on what you're choosing to open)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: check out open(), close(), and lseek(). They will open, close and move the pointer to where you want it in the file. In open() you need read/write" permission. I'm not really sure if you want to open the file in terminal or a separate editor.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach to opening documents, URLs, or applications on OS X is to use the [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html) API. (If you were using Cocoa, you would use `NSWorkspace`, which is built on top of Launch Services.) In particular, you can call `LSOpenCFURLRef()`.